# Is it Secure to Use Token Authentication and Let Users Execute Custom Javascript Code on Subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am helping to create a Rails app that uses Ember for a front end MVC. For the app, it is hosting user content accessed via subdomains. On the subdomains, the user can upload custom JS and CSS. What I'm wondering about is if token authentication on the root domain will be safe if stored in Ember from the custom JS people could upload and run on their subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the following:

- Don't use cookies on *.domain.com or use cookies at all.
- They can't run (or really display it unescaped in any way) the JS/CSS on your main site.
- The ember app with your token doesn't run on their sub-domain (obviously).
- They can't put HTML in a file with a different extension or even Content-Type on your subdomain (or you aren't using cookies). They could direct a user's web browser there and it'd display the HTML.  Be wary of phishing though (looks like it's your secure content).  I can't imagine you could prevent this easily other than not using cookies -- without 100% ensuring properly formatted JS/CSS which would present all kinds of problems.

You can limit cookies to domain.com and www.domain.com, but I don't recommend it (prone to mistakes). If you don't somebody can make a GET request through CSS or ie. an image tag (not to mention JavaScript) and it'll send the authenticated cookies to your server.  Remember unescaped input in their app can leave holes too.

If your token is stored in ember, and they have access to custom JS where the app is running of course it'll leave your token vulnerable.  If you run your ember app only on the www.domain.com, avoid cookies, storing the token only locally/in JS, you might be okay.

If they just put HTML code in a file with another extension and direct people there it'll be interpreted as HTML.